# Mirror JSON object changes in the DOM in jQuery (or possibly with other frameworks)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, reactjs

I need to build a web app that ideally would have a json object containing multiple properties and would update the DOM (html elements) when these properties change.

Example:

```
<ul data-id="elements">
<li data-id="01">Element 01</li>
<li data-id="02">Element 02</li>
<li data-id="03">Element 03</li>
<li data-id="04">Element 04</li>
</ul>
```

This UL would have a mirror JSON object which would hold all the values, and when I do something like this on the object:

```
elements.id('01') = "Change Value";
```

It would automatically (or by a method call) update the UL according to what was changed. In this case it would result in:

```
<ul data-id="elements">
<li data-id="01">Change Value</li>
<li data-id="02">Element 02</li>
<li data-id="03">Element 03</li>
<li data-id="04">Element 04</li>
</ul>
```

In a perfect scenario, I would somehow do that in Jquery, but I have no idea on where to start (I mean, if it's even possible without writing a whole new library for it). Any ideas or maybe already built libraries?

I know I could just change one element using a jquery function, but the idea is to have the object automatically update itself into the view.

I tried looking into Angular and React, but both seem a bit too far from what I already use (pure javascript and jquery). I still haven't figure what to use, could you guys give me some pointers?

Comment: http://jquerymy.com/ looks promising.

Comment: so, one question @joews , what I'm trying to achieve is called two-way data binding?

Comment: You need one-way data binding (update the DOM when data changes). Two-way binding also updates data when the DOM changes. Angular and jquery.my do Two-way, React is one-way. Since one-way is a subset of two-way either should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also tagged you question with reactjs. Therefore I recommend react for doing that.

A common way of doing this is to create two components, `List` and `ListItem`. The `List` component should handle the state, ajax calls and the transfer of list content as props to the child component `ListItem`.

This small [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/8914/) do exactly what you want.

```
var List = React.createClass({
    loadFromServer: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadFromServer();
    },
    handleClick: function() {
        var data = this.state.data;
        data[4].text = 'Change Value';

        this.setState({data: data});
    },
    render: function() {
        var listItems = this.state.data.map(function(item) {
            return <ListItem text={item.text} />;
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {listItems}
                </ul>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change first list item</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var ListItem = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <li>{this.props.text}</li>;
    }
});

React.render(<List url="/echo/json/" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

In [this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) you will learn how to build an easy react app.